# Node.js crashing automatically by mysql without any operation in it

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I am working with node.js and facing a problem with crashing of node . Error message shown below.

```
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
   at Protocol.end (/var/www/versions/project/js/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:78:13)
   at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/versions/project/js/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:81:28)
   at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
   at _stream_readable.js:919:16
   at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

I'm using mysql queries in node server..but at crashing time it does not have any operation on it... node crashing automatically different period of time.

Comment: Could well be timing out if you're not closing the connection after each request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that working with connection pools to grab a connection only when you need it is the best approach.

```
// do this once
var pool = mysql.createPool( opts );

// then, just before you need a connection do this
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) throw err;

    // use the connection

    // don't forget to release the connection when you are done...
    connection.release();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this is an error from nodejs mysql. "Connection lost, server closed the connection".
mysql server has closed the connection created.

i can't be so sure about the way you use mysql connection, you did not provided sample code snippet.

one way to solve this problem  is to re create a new connection  when the server close old connection, example code provided

```
    connection.on('error', function(error) {
        if(erroor.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') { 
          //re create the connection here again
          connection = mysql.createConnection(config);
        } else {                                      
          throw err;                                  
        }
      });
    }
```