# Error: Connection lost with SQl in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm using felixge/node-mysql module in my server to connect to the local database. 
After a while, it throws an error:

```
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/var/www/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:78:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:81:28)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

I connect to the sql both in a child process and its parent. The error is always thrown by the child process, so when it throws, the child dies.

I've already put handlers to capture the moment when the error happens in order to see why it happens, but it doesn't seems to be any apparent reason.

It's completely random, meaning that it can happen whether there's more or less activity in the server, or when the client requested some url, or even spontaneously.

In order to save the child from suicide, I've "solved" the problem putting a handler that reconnects the connection whenever the error happens.

However, I'm not happy yet, because I don't know WHY it happens and I can't follow any clue.

Is this a module bug?

P.D: Forget about pooling the connection, that's not an option right now.

P.P.D: The code is "PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST"

Comment: What I typically do to avoid the disconnection due to inactivity is to set up a recurring timer that periodically does `connection.ping()`, which sends a simple ping packet to the server.

Comment: I don't think that it's an inactivity error but I'll set up a timer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js crashing automatically by mysql without any operation in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358894/node-js-crashing-automatically-by-mysql-without-any-operation-in-it)